# Google Sign-In for iOSでのスコープ追加時にキーチェーンへの認証情報が保存されない

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c

CocoaPodsでGoogle Sign-In for iOS(Google/SignIn)を導入し、動作確認を行っているのですが、スコープを追加した場合keyChainに情報が登録されないように思われます。

前提
以下のサイトを参考にdelegate等の処理は追加されていること
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start

動作内容
1.アプリ内からコードにてSign Inの処理を実施。
スコープ追加有無でのそれぞれのSign In処理は以下のとおりです。

1-1スコープを追加しない場合

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

1-2スコープを追加する場合

```
NSString *tasksScope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks";
NSString *calendarScope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
NSArray *currentScopes = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes;

NSArray *additionalScopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tasksScope, calendarScope, nil];

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = [currentScopes arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:additionalScopes];

[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

2.アプリを終了(ホームボタンダブルタップ&上スワイプでアプリを落とす)

3.再度アプリを起動し、以下のメソッドでキーチェーンへの保存状態をチェック

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].hasAuthInKeychain
```

このような動作をした場合、スコープを追加しない場合はYES,追加する場合はNOが返却されます。

この挙動の場合、APIを叩く際に毎回ユーザーによる認証作業が発生するように思われます。
スコープを追加した場合でもキーチェーンに認証情報を保存するすべはあるでしょうか？(何か設定が足りていない等)

自前で認証情報を保存しようとしましたが、モバイルでのログオンの場合、トークンのリフレッシュ時に使用する"client_secret"が得られないため、実装出来ないと考え、中止しました。

また、Google TasksやCalendarについては個別にライブラリがあるかと思いますが、CocoaPodsでのインストールで、Swiftライブラリを共存させる場合(use_frameworks!を使用する場合)上手くライブラリをインストール出来ない事象があるようでこちらの方向も中止しています。

動作確認の実行環境は以下のとおりです。
iOS 9.3 (シミュレータ起動)
XCode Version 7.3

ご意見いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

hasAuthInKeychain する前に scopes を設定してみてください。